# PHP file_put_contents overwriting data

Tags: php, file, append

I'm attempting to write data to a .txt file using php file_put_contents with the following code.

```
file_put_contents($filevar, $userID, FILE_APPEND);
```

This successfully writes the $userID to $filevar, however even though FILE_APPEND is set, the file is overwritten on every execution.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? PHP4?

Comment: PHP version : 5.6.33

Answer (score 0):

I found my error,

I was working on getting the file to open earlier and was using some test statements. Opening problem was a permissions issue.

I was using fopen($filevar, 'w') to test if I could open the file, and this line was preventing the APPEND from working.